# groovy transform list into map using a groupBy max

Tags: groovy

Ok, this is a rather simple thing but I am not able to figure this out. I have a groovy list with some objects in it like:

```
def listOfTings = [
  ["type": "A", "value": 1],
  ["type": "B", "value": 3],
  ["type": "A", "value": 2],
  ["type": "B", "value": 2]
]
```

and I want to get a map out of it like groupBy(type) max(value):

```
["A": 2, "B": 3]
```

But I can not find a groupBy method and I have not figured it out using `collectEntries`. Is there some standard way to achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
listOfTings.groupBy { it.type }.collectEntries { [(it.key): it.value.max { it.value }.value] }
```

First `groupBy` will create a map of lists grouped by `type` field:

> [A:[[type:A, value:1], [type:A, value:2]], B:[[type:B, value:3], [type:B, value:2]]]

Next, `collectEntries` with `it.value.max { it.value }` will pick single entry with maximum `value` field:

> [A:[type:A, value:2], B:[type:B, value:3]]

Picking `value` with `it.value.max { it.value }.value` will extract only a `value` field instead of whole entry:

> [A:2, B:3]

Hope it helps :)